# Inefficient database query inside a for loop

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm writing code like below. It's using Django but this could happening in other cases. I'm also using Postgres as DB btw.

```
for elem in elemList:
    return_obj = someModle.objects.get(something=elem)
    if return_obj is not None:
        return_list.append(return_obj)
return return_list
```

Here a new database query would be generated and executed each time. Since the loop can be big, there could be massive database executions. I wonder if there's a better way to do this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: if `something=elem` condition does not match any object, you won't get `None`, `someModel` will raise a [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) exception.

Second, you could try this:

```
return_list = someModel.objects.filter(something__in=elemList)
return return_list
```